# How to clip an image as a clip (WPF C#)?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to cut off or fill a polygon region from the image as like:
[image]

or
[image]

I can implement it by the pixel operations such as

```
        double scale_x = image1.Source.Width / image1.ActualWidth;
        double scale_y = image1.Source.Height / image1.ActualHeight;
        Point[] scaledPoints = new Point[CropRegionPoints.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Point pt in CropRegionPoints)
        {
          scaledPoints[i++] = new Point(pt.X * scale_x, pt.Y * scale_y);
        }


        StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(BaseUriHelper.GetBaseUri(this), "1.png"));
        BitmapDecoder dec = BitmapDecoder.Create(sri.Stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
        BitmapFrame img = dec.Frames[0];
        byte[] pixels = new byte[img.PixelWidth * img.PixelHeight * 4];
        img.CopyPixels(pixels, img.PixelWidth * 4, 0);

        for (int x = 0; x < (int)image1.Source.Width; x++)
        {
          for (int y = 0; y < (int)image1.Source.Height; y++)
          {
            if (!IsInPolygon(scaledPoints, new Point(x, y)))
              continue;

            int k = y * img.PixelWidth + x;
            byte b = pixels[k * 4];
            byte g = pixels[k * 4 + 1];
            byte r = pixels[k * 4 + 2];
            byte a = pixels[k * 4 + 3];

            if (a != 0)
            {
              r = 255;
              g = 0;
              b = 0;

              if (rdoCropErase.IsChecked == true)
                a = 0;

              pixels[k * 4 + 3] = a;
              pixels[k * 4 + 2] = r;
              pixels[k * 4 + 1] = g;
              pixels[k * 4] = b;
            }
          }
        }

        // Write the modified pixels into a new bitmap and use that as the source of an Image
        var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(img.PixelWidth, img.PixelHeight, img.DpiX, img.DpiY, PixelFormats.Pbgra32, null);
        bmp.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, img.PixelWidth, img.PixelHeight), pixels, img.PixelWidth * 4, 0);
        image2.Source = bmp;
```

But it takes much time if the polygon is large.
I have found the WPF sample - Geometries Sample.
It clips an image with geometry.
[image]

But I couldn't find any polygon geometry.
Is there any way to clip or fill the polygon region?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you seen [Graphics.DrawPolygon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawpolygon?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: Your question needs more focus. Please tell us precisely what you want to do. Do not ask about multiple problems in a single question. While it is considerably easy to create a polygonal shape that is filled with an appropriately aligned ImageBrush, removing the cut out region from a bitmap (and possibly saving that to file) is a totally different story.

Comment: Wouldn't a "polygon geometry" basically be a `PathGeometry` where each `PathFigure` consists of a `LineSegment` list, ignoring all other possibilities?

Comment: After a little more googling... maybe use `PolyLineSegment` instead of `LineSegment`

Comment: @grek40 Or just a Polygon??

Comment: @Clemens if I understand you correctly, you mean the `System.Windows.Shapes.Polygon`. I suggested classes that are used to define a `Geometry`, because the question mentioned a known technique to clip with geometries. If you know how to clip with a shape, this would be a valid option of course...

Comment: @grek40 You can always get the RenderedGeometry from any Shape-derived class. It is however totally unclear what exactly OP is trying to do and why specifically they ask about geometries. "*Is there any way to clip or fill the polygon region?*" - are two totally different questions. The first would *perhaps* use a polygonal geometry while the second would *perhaps* use a polygonal shape.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers, Clemens, grek40.

yes, as you said, I want two purposes:
1. cut off the polygonal region
2. fill the polygonal region with a specific color.
I'm sorry I am not familiar with WPF coding.
I thought both need similar technique.
If you tell me any sample codes, it will be help very much.
Thank you a lot.

Comment: You want to do this in the GUI or in the original picture?
That is, you need to save the result or not?
Only the first applies to WPF.
And there is no need to cut to implement this.
You can simply overlay a polygon over the image in the desired position.